# Почему не работает INSERT?

Tags: php, sql

Код срабатывает, но значения не добавляются. В phpmyadmin sql запрос работает.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'connect.php';

$login = $_POST['login'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$imya = $_POST['imya'];
$familiya = $_POST['familiya'];
$pass_conf = $_POST['pass_conf'];

if($pass === $pass_conf) {

    mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `chitatel_logpass`(`login`, `pass`) 
                            VALUES ('$login','$pass');
                            INSERT INTO `chitatel`(`id_logpass`, `imya`, `familiya`) 
                            VALUES ('last_insert_id()','$imya','$familiya');");

    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Регистрация прошла успешно!';
    header('Location: ../index.php');

}
```

Comment: потому что mysqli_query не работает с несколькими запросами. ему нужен один запрос за раз.

Comment: так же стОит использовать https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, спасибо большое!

Comment: А в таком случает как занести последнюю id в переменную, чтобы вставить во вторую таблицу?

Comment: [mysqli_insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php#refsect1-mysqli.insert-id-examples)

Comment: `mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO 'chitatel_logpass'('login', 'pass')
                                VALUES ('$login','$pass')");

        mysqli_insert_id($last);

        mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO 'chitatel'('id_logpass', 'imya', 'familiya')
        VALUES ('$last','$imya','$familiya');");`

Таким образом? Не выходит ничего

Comment: Нет. читайте док с самого начала. что конкретно на вход принимает mysqli_insert_id и что **возвращает**